# Проблема с авторизацией SimpleMembership

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, mvc

Добрый день! Возникла проблема при работе: таблица с пользователями находится на sql-сервере на другой машине, при попытке пользователя авторизоваться или зарегистрироваться IIS сообщает (IIS выделенный сервер в сети ):

**При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра)**

В лог сервера падает:

**Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Не удалось инициализировать базу данных ASP.NET Simple Membership.**

На машине,которой делаю проект работает без проблем - проходит авторизация и регистрация, в базе создаются записи( сервер sql всё тот же), с сервера с iis проходит без проблем проверка соединения с сервером sql, другие страницы без проблем получают и отправляют записи в бд. Проблема такая возникает именно при работе с SimpleMembership. Подскажите, куда можно капнуть чтобы избавиться от напасти?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась банальной, не до конца изменил имя соединения в настройках контекста.